# Disable StackPanel Highlighting in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-interface

I have found very little information about this matter. Know that I am a newbie to C# and WPF:

I have a stack panel defined in a XAML file as such :

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" >
        <TextBlock Text="Locale: "  VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        <ComboBox x:Name="comboLocale" Width="60" VerticalAlignment="Center" SelectionChanged="comboLocale_SelectionChanged"/>
</StackPanel>
```

I want to disable the highlighting that happens when I MouseOver the stack panel, which creates a blue color inside the StackPanel for some reason. I don't have any special style set up yet. Some threads talked about setting OverridesDefaultStyle to TRUE, but this didn't seem to change anything. Also, StackPanel do not have a ControlTemplate available, so most of the solutions I found couldn't be applied since they refer to a Button or TextBlock.

Any input on the matter would be greatly appreciated!

-Regards

Comment: Is this inside a `ListBox` or something like that? Then the blue color comes from the `ListBoxItem`s' default style. You need to override that.

Comment: Add an image, try using snoop I order to see the visual tree

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`StackPanels` in general have no visual representation and are just layout containers which control placement of other elements. Given that you haven't set anything like `Background` on your `StackPanel`, it isn't what's causing the highlight you're seeing unless some other part of your XAML or code is modifying it. The behavior you describe sounds like the default behavior of a `Button` but without seeing more of your code it's hard to tell where the behavior is coming from.

Comment: Thanks for that, I now understand that the parent element "Menu" is causing the highlight. How would I then disable the highlight for <Menu> item?

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned in a comment you've found out you're actually looking at the expected behavior of a `Menu` as your culprit. You'll just need to edit the [MenuItem Control Template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747082%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), more specifically the `IsHighlighted` that's causing your highlight. You'd likely find something like [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/41ad0250-d0f9-4a24-b668-35020f0cfdf9/) helpful.

Or there's lots more various information found with a quick search for customizing a WPF `Menu` / `MenuItem`, hope this helps.